# Rewriting Lagrange Multiplier with non-linear optimization

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multipliers

*NOTE: if you have access to [*the book mentioned below*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199268010) , please skip to the part of this post marked with (*), as I will now provide a short summary of the relevant background information for my question.*

On page 216 of the book [Econometric Methods with Applications in Business and Economics (Heij et al., 2004)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199268010)  , the Lagrange Multiplier ($\lambda$) of the following equation:
$$\Lambda(\beta_1,\beta_2,\lambda) = S(\beta_1,\beta_2) + 2\lambda'\beta_2 \qquad H_0:\beta_2=0 \quad(1)$$
is proven to equal $nR^2$ of the regression of $e_R$ on $X=(X_1 X_2)$, where $X_2$ is a $n\times g$ block of regressors.
$$nR^2= \lambda \quad(2) $$

Here $e_R$ is obtained by regressing the restricted model ($H_0:\beta_2=0$) on $y$, which gives the model: $y = X_1b_R + e_R$.

(*)Part of the proof of $(2)$ is as follows:
$$ SSE = \hat{e}_R'\hat{e}_R = e_R' X(X'X)^{-1}X'e_R = (0 \quad e_R'X_2)(X'X)^{-1}(0 \quad e_R'X_2)'\\=e_R'X_2(X_2'M_1X_2)^{-1}X_2'e_R $$
Where $\hat{e}_R $ are the fitted values of $X$ on $e_R$ and $M_1 = I_n-X_1(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1'$

My question is with regard to the last step. Why is the lower $g\times g$ diagonal block of $(X'X)^{-1}$, multiplied with $(0 \quad e_R'X_2)$ on both sides, equal to $(X_2M_1X_2)^{-1}$?

Comment: What is "$M_1$" supposed to be?

Comment: I figured it out, it has to do with the definition of the inverse. Rewriting the inverse matrix of $(X'X)^{-1}$ gives a consistent answer.